# There is some errors releved from my GWT account

Tags: google-search-console

The GWT has sent the bellow message:

Dear webmaster,
Your smartphone users will be happier if they don’t land on error- or non-existent pages, so we recommend you make sure that your pages return the appropriate HTTP code. Currently, Googlebot for smartphones detects a significant increase in URLs returning a 200 (available) response code, but we think they should return an HTTP 404 (page not found) code.
Recommended actions
Check the Smartphone Crawl Errors page in Webmaster Tools.
Return a 404 (page not found) or 410 (gone) HTTP response code in response to a request for a non-existent URL.
Improve the user experience by configuring your site to display a custom 404 page when returning a 404 response code.

Now how to resolved this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you made any significant changes lately? Like changing URLs to all pages?

First of, make sure your pages are available and working with the URLs. Try searching yourself on google with "site:yourdomain.com". Are these pages correct or do they not exist?

You should also check that IF your page does not exist (yourdomain.com/blahblah), it will return HTTP404 (Not found) and not HTTP200 (OK). You can see this in Chrome Developer Tools. Go to Network tab, reload the page, check the Status column for your HTML page.

How you change the HTTP code depends on your web server and language. In PHP you can use header().